# Angular 2, How to reload a component after change?

Tags: angular2-routing

I got a problem with routing: when I Login successfully, the router navigate to the HomeComponent but the HeaderBar don't have any change, Which need refresh page (f5) to see the change. Can anyone help me? I don't want to use the `window.location.reload()`

The sample code below:

1. I have a component:HeaderBar (a part of HomeComponent) - which include button Login/Logout.

   ```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
        <li>
          <button [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
        <li>
          <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

   constructor() {
     this.isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('username') ? true : false;
   }
   ```
2. I have other component: LoginComponent.

   `<button (click)="login()"></button>`

   ```
   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   login(): void {
         localStorage.setItem('username','myname');
         this.router.navigate(['/']);    //Navigate to the home component
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr for this?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UzEON1?p=preview This is the sample code but I don't know why the plunker preview don't work